# Product images not showing for some product - Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.3

I am new to Magento, Facing some issue with product images : 
Total product count  : around 550 
1) On Product Detail page images are not showing for some product, showing error 500 in console. `(/pub/media/catalog/product/cache - Cache url : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()`)

2) Does `php bin/magento catalog:images:resize` , Help's to generate the missing images in cache folder ?  (Is it a good idea to run this ?)

3) What I have to do to generate new images in cache folder (`/pub/media/catalog/product/cache`)

Note : Also, the product images are showing correctly in backend & image files are present inside `/pub/media/catalog/product/H/i`.
If anyone

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem i.e Magento not creating images in `/pub/media/catalog/product/cache` folder.
I have run the following command that creates a images for all the sizes for each product.
Here is the link for reference : [Magento Product resize guide](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-images.html#resize-catalog-images)

Steps to follow :

- 1. Remove cache folder from  (/pub/media/catalog/product/)
- 2. Run Command : `php bin/magento catalog:images:resize`
- 3. Response : Product images resized successfully. ( Displays to
     confirm the command succeeded.)